# Using captured groups in Regex

Tags: regex

I want to match a string where there are 5 characters where first four characters are A-Z and 5th is a digit. Also the first and the fourth character should be same.

I have a regex: `[A-Z]{4}\d`

However this wont check if 1st and 4th character are same. Please help

Comment: This smells like homework....

Answer (score 4):

**Regex:** `^([A-Z])[A-Z]{2}\1\d$`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `([A-Z])` capture first character.
>
> **3.** `[A-Z]{2}` match next two character which can be in `A-Z`
>
> **4.** `\1` using captured group which contains first character of string.
>
> **5.** `\d` a digit which can be `0-9`
>
> **6.** `$` for end of string.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FLTEbl/1)

Comment: awesome it works thanks

Comment: @AkshayBhasin Welcome.. friend .. :)